# How to apply Stoke's Theorem in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $B =$ {$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$}. Consider $S=$ {$(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z = x^2 + y^2 ; x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$} over $B$, oriented so that the function $\alpha: B \to S$ defined by $\alpha = (x,y,x^2 +y^2)$ is orientation-preserving. Identify the boundary of S ($\partial S$) and compute:

$\int_{\partial S}$ $(cos(z))dx + (xz + tan(y))dy + y^2z^3dz$.

I'm having trouble trying to identify the boundary of $S$. $S$ appears to be the intersection of the solid unit rod with the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$.

So would the boundary of $S$ be the surface of paraboloid for $0 \leq z \leq 1$

If so, would it be appropriate to apply Stokes Theorem? But how do I identify the unit normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ is just the surface of the paraboloid, not a three dimensional shape as you seem to be thinking.  The boundary is the circle $\{(x,y,1):x^2+y^2=1\}$.

You can evaluate your integral directly now by parameterizing this circle.  Or you could use Stoke's theorem to turn this into a surface integral, but that is probably harder.